# What is wrong with my Clean program which compiler give the error "cannot unify demanded type with offered type"

Tags: clean-language

I'm trying to write my PDF parser and I got stick for this type checking failure and it bothered me for days.

Here's my app.icl

```
module app

import StdEnv

Start = "Hello, world!"


:: ParseResult a
    = ParseOk a [Char]
    | ParseFail [Char]

match :: [Char] Real -> ([Char] -> (ParseResult Real))
match x y = matchYes x y
matchYes :: [Char] Real [Char] -> ParseResult Real
matchYes [] t _          = ParseOk t
matchYes [_:_] _ []      = ParseFail []
matchYes [x:xs] t [y:ys] = if (x == y) (matchYes xs t ys) (ParseFail [])
```

the output is

```
Type error [app.icl,14,matchYes]: near (case ... ) : cannot unify demanded type with offered type:
 [Char] -> ParseResult Real
 ParseResult Real
```

I run `nitrile build` and it fails. I really don't get it.
As far as I know, `matchYes` always fit the type `[Char] Real [Char] -> ParseResult Real`

Comment: Sorry for my typo in the title earlier, I know the question wasn't phrased nice, so I tried to edit it to make it feel more friendly. I apologize for my rudeness, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ParseOk a [Char]
> ```

`ParseOk` takes two arguments: one of type `a` (`Real` in this case) and one of type `[Char]`.

> ```
> matchYes [] t _          = ParseOk t
> ```

Here you're partially applying `ParseOk` to a single argument of type `Real`. So what you're left with is a function of type `[Char] -> ParseResult Real` when the expected type would have been just `ParseResult Real`.

Comment: wow thank you! feel so happy for your kindness!